# Composer - how to autoload only needed modules

Tags: composer-php, autoload

While using composer autoload function, I faced annoying case.

For example for following situation:

> I have 10 modules installed so far, and in the specific PHP, I just
>   want to load only needed module with it's dependencies.

What can I do?

If I do

```
require "composer/vendor/autoload.php";
```

it will load all modules' name space, and I DO NOT WANT THAT!

---

**So let me explain exact sample case.**

I have a `Facebook SDK v4.0`, which I manually downloaded last time. And there is code snap in, let say, `a.php` which is using this, by following code:

```
require 'facebook_v4/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
```

Now, I have downloaded `Facebook SDK v5` just by composer, with running following command:

```
composer require facebook/graph-sdk
```

And because I need to use other modules downloaded via composer, I added following line at very fist line of the `a.php` file:

```
require "composer/vendor/autoload.php";
```

Now it turns out it totally uses `Facebook SDK v5` instead of `v4`, that 's why I just want to know the way to load ONLY needed modules by composer.

---

Please help me to figure out this case.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "it will load all modules"? AFAIK, Composer does not autoload classes that are not used

Comment: @NicoHaase autoload.php loads all classes which I am quite sure.

Comment: autoload.php tells the autoloader where to find classes when they should be included, but does not include any classes on its own. That is how the autoloader works... or can you tell me what you mean by "loads all classes"?

Comment: the fact of requiring the composer `vendor/autoload.php` file doesn't means`PHP` will load all module, the module that you want to use will be load only when you you file you are using class that are in that module by instantiating them or by using some static method on one class of composer package

Comment: @yvesdaxmaz okay, I have changed the question, so I do not want to load all name spaces, but only some of them. Any solution?

Comment: the answer is pretty the same anything will be load only when you use it, and namespace is just a wrapper of functions, classes, interface and so on. you don't load namespace exactly but things that are in that namespace

Comment: If that's the case then why does an empty script take 10ms to run on the CLI, but it takes 60ms when I add `require 'vendor/autoload.php'`? Composer's autoloader can and definitely does run actual code. Many packages specify paths in the `autoload.files` section of `composer.json`, and each of those is included by the autoloader.